# Reset windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reset, factory-defaults

Currently, I have have windows 10 2004 version. When I bought the laptop,It had 1803 version. If I factory reset the laptop, Will it turn back to 1803 version ? What to do to stay with 2004 version. (I do not need third party apps)

Comment: If you perform a Reset from within you will keep 2004.  If you perform a Factory Reset outside of Windows, it entirely depends, on the image being used.  There is no reason NOT to use the Reset feature from within Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform the reset from within the Windows 10 Settings page (Settings > Update & security > Recovery), Windows will always keep the last version of Windows, in your case Windows 2004.

You can either choose to keep your files or do a factory-like reset.
If you reset from external tools you will have to update windows manually.

Here a summarized screenshot:
[Win 10 Reset dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiLtr.png)